# Google App Engine JPA getting com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils$ChildWithoutParentException

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

Update: I found out the problem in my case is that I am generating the FbUser primary key by myself using keyfactory.createKey() method. If I change it to auto generate it works fine. But the problem is I don't want to because my data is in String format for the key. So I need to change the type from String to Key manually and then persist it.

I am using Google App Engine JPA and trying to have a oneToMany relationship amongst my entities.

```
@Entity
public class DummyParent{


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

//@Unowned
@OneToMany(targetEntity=FbUser.class, mappedBy="dummyP", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private ArrayList<FbUser> users;
}
```

And here FbUser as the child :

```
@Entity
public class FbUser {

@Id
private Key id;
private String name;
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private DummyParent dummyP;
}
```

So after that I instantiate the parent class set its id and set the users. But I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils$ChildWithoutParentException: Detected attempt to establish DummyParent(no-id-yet) as the parent of FbUser("1322222") but the entity identified by FbUser("1322222") has already been persisted without a parent.  A parent cannot be established or changed once an object has been persisted.
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.extractChildKey(EntityUtils.java:939)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.StoreFieldManager.getDatastoreObjectForCollection(StoreFieldManager.java:967)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.StoreFieldManager.storeFieldInEntity(StoreFieldManager.java:394)
```

Any idea why this is happening?
P.s. HRD is already enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you persisted FbUser without a parent entity and then try to change it at a later date, and GAE Datastore doesn't allow that (as the message says pretty clearly). You present no persistence code so no comment is possible other than guesswork.

Solution : persist it correctly (parent first, then child), or persist them as *Unowned*.

Comment: I have persisted the parent. I am able to persist the whole thing when using app engine to generate keys automatically. But when it comes to me assigning the key as a string and then convert it to Key using Keyfactory.createKey method then it throws the above error. So I just left it the way it is and went with using auto key generation although that might have not been the best option for me according the code we already had.